# Is Socket.IO connection state recovery supported by the Python server?

Tags: python, socket.io

The Socket.IO docs describe [Connection state recovery](https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery) and how to implement it in JavaScript. It states, "Connection state recovery must be enabled by the server". However, I cannot find any mention of connection state recovery in the [Socket.IO Python server docs](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html).

I'm using this to initialize the server (see [AsyncServer docs](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncserver-class)):

```
import socketio

sio_server = socketio.AsyncServer(
    async_mode='asgi',
    cors_allow_origins=[],  # allow ONLY FastAPI
)
```

In a simple test, I disconnected WiFi between my Python Socket.IO client and Python Socket.IO server. After 30 seconds, the client died with `socketio.exceptions.TimeoutError`. After reconnecting, the server, too, reported `socketio.exceptions.TimeoutError`.

**Is the connection state recovery feature implemented in the Python server?** If so, where is the documentation? How do I enable it?